# Align logo exactly in the center

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

```
 CSS:
 #header_bar
{
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width:100%;
}

.langpnl
{
float:right;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 0px;
position:relative;
width:45px; 
height:16px; 
font-size:7pt;
}

#imgLogo
{
width: 156px; 
height: 42px;
}

<!-- header.ascx -->
<div id="header_bar">
<div align="center">
    <a href="<%=AppPath%>" target="_parent" >
        <img id="imgLogo" runat="server" src="~/images/UI/logo.jpg"   border="0" /></a>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage"  class="langpnl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="">EN</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-ES">ES</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /header.ascx -->
```

I am trying to align image in the center and dropdown box to the right  top corner. Currently I am able to do it but the Image is slighty to the left. If I remove the dropdown box only then it gets in the center.
In the system browsers you cannot figure it out but this is a mobile website & in mobile view you can figure out the difference.

Comment: align="center" has been deprecated for a good while now: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp

Comment: This is a client-side problem. Please show your resulting HTML, not your ASP code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/NzZak/

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely position the dropdown - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3691612)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- header.ascx -->
<div id="header_bar">
<div id="header_logo_holder">
    <a href="<%=AppPath%>" target="_parent" >
        <img id="imgLogo" runat="server" src="~/images/UI/logo.jpg"   border="0" /></a>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage"  class="langpnl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="">EN</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-ES">ES</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /header.ascx -->
```

CSS code for "header_logo_holder"

```
#header_logo_holder {
width: 156px;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.langpnl` has a `position:relative` it still takes up room in your positioning flow.
Try:

```
.langpnl { 
  position:absolute; 
  right: 0;
}
#header_bar {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header_bar {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; /* New */
}

.langpnl {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 45px;
  height: 16px; 
  font-size: 7pt;
  vertical-align: top; /* New */
}

#imgLogo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  border:0px; /* New */
}
```

This solves that issue.